# How do I configure spring security 5.4.1 via xml such that oauth2 logout works correctly?

Tags: xml, spring-security, oauth-2.0, openid-connect, logout

I'm attempting to convert our web app that currently uses basic authentication to use oauth2 instead. In preparation for this project I upgraded our Spring and Spring Security from v3 to v5 so we could leverage the OAuth2 functionality in Spring Security 5.4.1. Our web app still configures spring and spring security via xml and it does not use spring boot.

I've now got it configured such that the oauth2 login process works correctly, or at least it appears to work correctly. However, I'm having difficulty configuring it so when a user logs out, the session is also ended in the authorization server and the login page from the authorization server is displayed to the user. Currently when I log out, I can see in the logs that the session is invalidated and the JSESSIONID cookie is deleted, but I don't see it sending a request to the authorization server's 'end-session-endpoint' to end the session in the authorization server. Then I see that when spring security wants to login in the user again, the authorization server responses saying the user's session is still active and skips the login page.

It appears the correct way to configure the logout for oauth2 is to set the 'success-handler-ref' attribute of the 'logout' element to a reference of an 'OidcClientInitiatedLogoutSuccessHandler' bean. However, the OidcClientInitiatedLogoutSuccessHandler constructor requires a reference to the ClientRegistrationRepository bean and the 'client-registrations' element that configures the ClientRegistrationRepository 'bean' does not appear to have an 'id' or 'name' property that I can pass to the OidcClientInitiatedLogoutSuccessHandler constructor.

I did try to create my own ClientRegistrationRepository bean to replace the use of the 'client-registrations' element in the hopes it would allow me to configure that class with an 'id' property. However, when I did that it broke the login process and I'm not sure why.

Here is how my security xml file looks when oauth2 login is working correctly and logout is not. Sorry if I included too much of our xml file. I figured more is better.

```
    <security:http pattern="/resources/**" security="none"/>
    <security:http pattern="/mobile/startup" security="none"/>
    <security:http pattern="/mobile/debuginfo" security="none"/>
    <security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" disable-url-rewriting="true">
        <headers disabled="true"/>
        <csrf disabled="true"/>
        <expression-handler ref="webExpressionHandler"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/identity/login" access="permitAll"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/mobilelogin" access="permitAll"/>
        ...
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()"/>   
        <access-denied-handler error-page="/error/access_denied"/>

        <oauth2-client>
            <authorization-code-grant/>
        </oauth2-client>

        <oauth2-login oidc-user-service-ref="hwOidcUserService"/>

        <logout logout-url="/logout"
                invalidate-session="true"
                delete-cookies="JSESSIONID"
                logout-success-url="/"/>
    </security:http>

    <security:client-registrations>
        <client-registration registration-id="idsrv"
                             client-id="homeofficecodeui"
                             provider-id="idsrv"
                             client-name="Home Office and Mobile"
                             client-secret="<SECRET>"
                             authorization-grant-type="authorization_code"
                             client-authentication-method="basic"
                             redirect-uri="<CLIENT_BASE_URL>/login/oauth2/code/idsrv"
                             scope="openid,offline_access,profile,email,homeofficeapi"/>

        <provider provider-id="idsrv"
                  issuer-uri="<AUTH_SERVER_BASE_URL>"
                  authorization-uri="<AUTH_SERVER_BASE_URL>/connect/authorize?sec_host=<CLIENT_BASE_URL>"/>
    </security:client-registrations>

    <beans:bean id="hwOidcUserService"
                class="com.example.service.HWOidcUserService"/>

    <beans:bean id="webExpressionHandler" class="org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler">
        <beans:property name="permissionEvaluator" ref="permissionEvaluator"/>
    </beans:bean>
    <beans:bean id="requestContextFilter" class="org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter"/>

    <beans:bean id="customAuthenticationEntryPoint"
        class="com.example.security.CustomAuthenticationEntryPoint" />

    <beans:bean id="authenticationFailureHandler" class="com.example.security.CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler">
        <beans:property name="exceptionMappings">      
            <beans:props>
                <beans:prop key="org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException">/login?error=BAD_CREDENTIALS</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="org.springframework.security.authentication.CredentialsExpiredException">/login?error=CREDENTIALS_EXPIRED</beans:prop>            
                <beans:prop key="org.springframework.security.authentication.LockedException">/login?error=ACCOUNT_LOCKED</beans:prop>   
                <beans:prop key="com.example.exception.AccountManuallyLockedException">/login?error=ACCOUNT_LOCKED_MANUALLY</beans:prop> 
                <beans:prop key="org.springframework.security.authentication.DisabledException">/login?error=AGENCY_DISABLED</beans:prop>       
                <beans:prop key="org.springframework.security.authentication.InternalAuthenticationServiceException">/login?error=UNKNOWN_ERROR</beans:prop>
            </beans:props>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="passwordValidator" class="com.example.security.PasswordValidator">
    </beans:bean>

    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider ref="alternateCustomAuthenticationProvider"/>
        <authentication-provider ref="alternate2CustomAuthenticationProvider"/>
        <authentication-provider ref="customAuthenticationProvider"/>
    </authentication-manager>
    
    <global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled">
       <expression-handler ref="expressionHandler"/>
    </global-method-security>
    
    <beans:bean id="expressionHandler" class="org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler">
       <beans:property name="permissionEvaluator" ref="permissionEvaluator"/>
    </beans:bean>
    
    <beans:bean id="permissionEvaluator" class="com.example.security.CustomPermissionEvaluator">
    </beans:bean>
```

And here are the changes that I think I need to make but I can't figure out what the ref to the clientRegistrationRepository is:

```
    <security:http ...
        ...

        <logout logout-url="/logout"
                invalidate-session="true"
                delete-cookies="JSESSIONID"
                success-handler-ref="logoutSuccessHandler"/>
    </security:http>

    <beans:bean id="logoutSuccessHandler"
                class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.oidc.web.logout.OidcClientInitiatedLogoutSuccessHandler">
        <beans:constructor-arg ref="clientRegistrationRepository"/> <-- Error. Can't figure out what the ref to the clientRegistrationRepository is.
        <beans:property name="postLogoutRedirectUri" value="/"/>
    </beans:bean>
```

I've looked through the Spring Security Reference but unfortunately the section on the OidcClientInitiatedLogoutSuccessHandler does not include an xml sample.

Does anyone know what changes I need to make to get the oauth2 logout process to work correctly?

**Hack Solution Update**

I've come up with a solution that is probably in the 'hack' category. I added a custom logout filter to my filter chain that calls the authorization server 'end-session-endpoint' to log the user out in the authorization server. It uses the OidcClientInitiatedLogoutSuccessHandler class and it gets a handle to the ClientRegistrationRepository via the ApplicationContext.

I put this new filter just before the LogoutFilter since the LogoutFilter nulls out the authentication in the SecurityContext and the authentication is needed for the OidcClientInitiatedLogoutSuccessHandler to work correctly.

Here is the new custom logout filter:

```
package com.example.web.login;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.oidc.web.logout.OidcClientInitiatedLogoutSuccessHandler;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.ClientRegistrationRepository;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.InMemoryClientRegistrationRepository;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.RequestMatcher;
import org.springframework.util.Assert;
import org.springframework.web.filter.GenericFilterBean;

public class OAuth2LogoutFilter extends GenericFilterBean implements ApplicationContextAware {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(OAuth2LogoutFilter.class);

    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    private ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository;

    private OidcClientInitiatedLogoutSuccessHandler logoutSuccessHandler;

    private RequestMatcher logoutRequestMatcher;

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        if (logger.isDebugEnabled())
            logger.debug("in init()");

        Assert.notNull(applicationContext, "applicationContext can not be null");

        clientRegistrationRepository = applicationContext.getBean(InMemoryClientRegistrationRepository.class);
        Assert.notNull(clientRegistrationRepository, "clientRegistrationRepository can not be null");

        logoutSuccessHandler = new OidcClientInitiatedLogoutSuccessHandler(clientRegistrationRepository);
        logoutSuccessHandler.setPostLogoutRedirectUri("<CLIENT_BASE_URL>/logoutAfterOAuth");

        logoutRequestMatcher = new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout");

        if (logger.isDebugEnabled())
            logger.debug("end init()");
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(final ServletRequest request,
                         final ServletResponse response,
                         final FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        doFilter((HttpServletRequest) request, (HttpServletResponse) response, chain);
    }

    private void doFilter(final HttpServletRequest request,
                          final HttpServletResponse response,
                          final FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        if (logger.isDebugEnabled())
            logger.debug("in doFilter()" +
                    "\n\trequest: " + request +
                    "\n\tresponse: " + response +
                    "\n\tchain: " + chain);

        if (requiresLogout(request)) {
            Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
            if (this.logger.isDebugEnabled())
                this.logger.debug("Logging out auth: " + auth);

            logoutSuccessHandler.onLogoutSuccess(request, response, auth);
            return;
        }

        chain.doFilter(request, response);

        if (logger.isDebugEnabled())
            logger.debug("end doFilter()");
    }

    protected boolean requiresLogout(final HttpServletRequest request) {
        if (this.logoutRequestMatcher.matches(request))
            return true;

        if (this.logger.isTraceEnabled())
            this.logger.trace("Did not match request to " + logoutRequestMatcher);

        return false;
    }
}
```

And here is the changes to the security xml file:

```
<security:http ...
    ...

    <custom-filter ref="oauth2LogoutFilter" before="LOGOUT_FILTER"/>

    ...

    <logout logout-url="/logoutAfterOAuth"
            invalidate-session="true"
            delete-cookies="JSESSIONID"
            logout-success-url="/"/>

</security:http>

<beans:bean id="oauth2LogoutFilter"
            class="com.example.web.login.OAuth2LogoutFilter"/>
```

I'm still hoping someone can tell me the correct non-hacky solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

In my XML for the `OidcClientInitiatedLogoutSuccessHandler` bean definition, I used:

```
autowire=“constructor”
```

That way I let spring inject the `ClientRegistrationRepository` since there isn’t an ID reference.